# Article with absolute adjectives

Tags: adjectives, articles

Can we use article with absolute adjectives?

Examples:

> a) He has complete game of the top10 pros.
>   b) He has the complete game of the top 10 pros.
>   a) It's perfect copier ever invented.
>   b) It's the perfect copier ever invented.

Comment: Single nouns almost always require an article in English, whether there's a no-graded adjective or not. Unfortunately though, the choice of adjectives doesn't seem to make much sense here. Maybe you meant to use 'the most complete' (is that right?) That would then make sense to ask if it is semantically workable.

Answer (score 1):

First, articles apply to nouns, not adjectives. English normally requires an article for a singular noun whether or not the noun is modified by an adjective. There is not an exception for non-gradable adjectives.

Second, **the complete game** in the sense meant in your first example is close to being an idiom. (I suspect it was made up by sports reporters, who are paid to make the trivial interesting. Mitch's comment indicates that the idiomatic meaning of "the complete game" is not even universally recognized.) You cannot freely alter idioms, and consequently they do not serve well as examples of grammatical rules.

Third, your second example is poor English grammar in both renditions. The sense of **perfect** in your example is gradable. The literal sense of **perfect** is admittedly non-gradable. But **perfect** is much more frequently used in a looser sense to mean **almost ideal**, and that sense is subject to gradation. The idiomatic and grammatical way to render your second example is **It's the most perfect copier yet invented.**